# Localization of strings of Uber iOS SDK

Tags: ios, localization, uber-api

I can't find a way to localize the strings of the Uber API for iOS. Specifically, what I want is to localize the strings for the RideRequestButton.

The API provide a method for this or you have to work around?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We bundle the localization strings with the sdk: https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/blob/master/source/UberRides/Resources/en.lproj/Localizable.strings

You can create a new l10n bundle for your locale. By default, we use the locale set in the system preferences.

Comment: I have to guess how to do it, but still very usefull!